# Logging in OpenShift 3.7 issue

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise, openshift-3, efk

I am using Ansible to install logging (EFK) in OpenShift 3.7 with below parameters,

```
openshift_logging_install_logging=true
openshift_logging_kibana_hostname=kibana.example.com
openshift_logging_es_cluster_size=3
openshift_logging_es_number_of_shards=3
openshift_logging_es_number_of_replicas=1
openshift_logging_es_nodeselector={"region":"infra"}
openshift_logging_kibana_nodeselector={"region":"infra"}
openshift_logging_curator_nodeselector={"region":"infra"}
```

But it fails with message, I am not sure why , I tried with openshift_logging_es_cluster_size=1 , it works fine that way. But I want cluster size to be 3. Can anyone help me on this-

```
2018-01-30 18:08:27,734 p=30740 u=root |  FAILED - RETRYING: Waiting for logging-es-data-master-8bm7g3s4 to finish scaling up (60 retries left).
2018-01-30 18:08:59,582 p=30740 u=root |  FAILED - RETRYING: Waiting for logging-es-data-master-8bm7g3s4 to finish scaling up (59 retries left).
2018-01-30 18:09:30,763 p=30740 u=root |  FAILED - RETRYING: Waiting for logging-es-data-master-8bm7g3s4 to finish scaling up (58 retries left).
2018-01-30 18:10:02,003 p=30740 u=root |  FAILED - RETRYING: Waiting for logging-es-data-master-8bm7g3s4 to finish scaling up (57 retries left).
2018-01-30 18:10:33,239 p=30740 u=root |  FAILED - RETRYING: Waiting for logging-es-data-master-8bm7g3s4 to finish scaling up (56 retries left).
2018-01-30 18:11:04,456 p=30740 u=root |  FAILED - RETRYING: Waiting for logging-es-data-master-8bm7g3s4 to finish scaling up (55 retries left)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use commandline to describe your logging-es-data-master-* pod,you may find that other two nodes are lacking in cpu or memory in events.
Because the logging-es-data-master-* pod needs 8G memory by default.
There may be other reasons.